# Calling a string inside a while loop

Tags: java

so I'm working on an activity and I need help on figuring out how will i get a string that inside a while loop.
The code below is just a part of my activity so please disregard the doubles and char
The code:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class ignCalcu {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char operator;
        Double num1, num2, answer;
        System.out.println("Welcome to CalcuLegends!");
     while (true){
        System.out.println("Before you use the Calcore, would you like to set an IGN first?");
        System.out.println("Yes or No?");
        String start = input.nextLine();
        if (start.equals("Yes") || start.equals("yes")){
           System.out.println("What is your favorite color?");
           String color = input.nextLine(); 
           System.out.println("What word describes you the best?");
           String word = input.nextLine();
           System.out.println("What is your favorite animal?");
           String animal = input.nextLine();
         
           String ign = (" "+color+"_"+word+"_"+animal+" ");
           System.out.println("Hi" + ign + "! You are now using Calcore.");
           break;
        }
        System.out.println(ign);
       }
       }
       }
```

And here is the error:

source_file.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println(ign);

Symbol:   variable ign

location: class ignCalcu
1 error

Comment: `ign` in `System.out.println(ign);` does not have access to the `ign` scope (where it's declared)

Comment: declare your String outside of the loop

Comment: also, minor remark: if (start.equals("Yes") || start.equals("yes")) should be rewritten to: if ( "yes".equalsIgnoreCase(start)) -> this covers "yes", "Yes", "yeS", .. and any other option. It also won't throw an NPE if start would happen to be null

Comment: Ok, thank you so much @Stultuske!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `String ign` inside your `if` statement, which means it will be only available within that `if` statement (this is its scope).

You are trying to use the `ign` variable outside the `if` statement and as a consequence you get the error. You can fix this by declaring the variable `ign` outside the `if` statement as follows:

```java
public class ignCalcu {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char operator;
        Double num1, num2, answer;
        System.out.println("Welcome to CalcuLegends!");
        while (true){
            System.out.println("Before you use the Calcore, would you like to set an IGN first?");
            System.out.println("Yes or No?");
            String start = input.nextLine();
            String ign = "";
            if (start.equals("Yes") || start.equals("yes")){
                System.out.println("What is your favorite color?");
                String color = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("What word describes you the best?");
                String word = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("What is your favorite animal?");
                String animal = input.nextLine();

                ign = (" "+color+"_"+word+"_"+animal+" ");
                System.out.println("Hi" + ign + "! You are now using Calcore.");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(ign);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ign variable is inside if block and so not visible outside if block when you do System.out.println().

You can declare variable ign outside if block

```
String ign = null;
if (start.equals("Yes") || start.equals("yes")){ {
    //Your other code
    ign = (" "+color+"_"+word+"_"+animal+" ");
}
```